# Get string non localized

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to get string from string file called "Common.strings" that I have created to store some non translated strings like URLs and names.

So, to do that I created the a strings file called "Common":

[image: strings files]

I find the way using localizedString like below:

```
Bundle.main.localizedString(forKey: "api_url", value: "", table: "Common")
```

There are another way to do that ? The code that I am using is right ?

I am asking cause I don't want a "localized" string

Comment: "*The code that I am using is right ?*" Have you tested it? Does it work?

Comment: Why are you putting into localization when you don't want the string localized? What's wrong with a plist, for example?

Comment: @esqew of course I tested that and this works. My question is about there are another better way to do that ?

Comment: @Sulthan I didn't know that I can use plist to do that. Do you have some example for me ?

Answer (score 0):

Declare the constant values as such in code, there is no need to create a `.strings` file.

E.g. `let urlString = "http://mywebsite.com"`

You could also put it inside a struct to effectively namespace your constants:

```
struct Constants {
    static let urlString = "http://www.mywebsite.com"
}
```

Giving you something like: `let baseUrlString = Constants.urlString`

Comment: I would call it `AppConfiguration` or something similar. Having something called `Constants` usually ends with programmers putting *all* constants there even if the constants have nothing in common.

Comment: It's a fair point. Although whatever you name it, some developers will still end up putting all constants in there if its global :) I recommend keeping it only in the scope the constants are needed (so could be private for example)

Comment: It's a good solution, I think I will use it. But I am looking on iOS something like that http://tools.android.com/recent/non-translatablestrings